# pre-emphasis filter - parameter a

Tags: filters, impulse-response

Can someone give my a link to study to solve this problem.
I can not find any formula for this problem...

Suppose we filter singals with the below pre-emphasis filter:

$y(n)=x(n) - ax(n-1)$

How can I compute $a$ if I know that:

- fs=10.000Hz
- length 100 in which 98 is zero.
- Frequency response at 2100Hz is 1.3429 dB

I don't want the solution only a hint I found this in my notes: 10log10(a^2*w^2+1)=db but with this formula i don't use some information which given.

Thanks

Comment: *"Impulse response at 2100Hz is 1.3429 dB"*  i really dunno what that means.  did you mean *"**Frequency** response at 2100Hz is 1.3429 dB"*?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes, I am sorry. Do you know any formula for this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "length 100 in which 98 is zero"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is right...
$$h[n]=\delta[n]-a\delta[n-1]$$
$$H(e^{jw})= 1- ae^{-jw} =(1-a\cos(\omega))+ja\sin(\omega)$$
$$|H(e^{j\omega})|= \sqrt{1 + a^2 -2a\cos(\omega)}$$
$$DB_\omega \triangleq 20\log(|H(e^{j\omega})|)$$
$$20\log((1 + a^2 -2a\cos(\omega))^{1/2})= DB_\omega$$
$$1 + a^2 -2a\cos(\omega)= 10^{DB_\omega/10}$$
$$a^2 -2a\cos(\omega) +1-10^{DB_\omega/10}=0$$

with $\omega = 2 \pi \frac{2100}{10000}, \ DB_\omega=1.343 \ \Rightarrow \ a \in \{0.9, -0.4026\}$

$a = -0.4026$ results in a low-pass pre-emphasis whereas $a = 0.9$ results in a high-pass pre-emphasis.

Comment: Pre-emphasis usually emphasizes the high frequencies, so I'd go for the $a=0.9$ solution.

Comment: @Bulent S. Could you please explain me this line:
H(ejw)=1−ae−jw=(1−acos(ω))+jasin(ω)
Which formula did you use?

Comment: use $e^{j\theta} = cos(\theta) + j\sin(\theta)$ This is the Euler' Relation.

Comment: @BulentS. in this solution you don't use the information that the singal has length n=100(98 is zero), right?

Comment: I dont know how to use that information? :) What do you mean by signal length n=100 (98) zero? (as Matt-L already asked it)

Comment: @BulentS. "The Impulse response has been choosen to have length 100 samples (98 zero)"

Comment: @BulentS. That's the reason why I tried to solve the problem like this: http://tinyurl.com/pmk7b98  but I couldn't ...

Comment: OK, that information is already available in the LCCDE of your filter, from which I have directly deduced the form of the himpulse response h[n] having only two taps, assuming a linear time invariant casual filter ;)

Comment: @BulentS. Thank you very much, all the best. The way I tried to solve (previous post-image) is wrong ? (not the solution itself but the sequence)

Comment: Yes it is wrong. It seems you try, DFT X[k] of h[n], instead go with DTFT $H(e^{j\omega})$